# How Can I Detect / select Seam edge in shader editor

Tags: modeling, materials, shader-nodes

How can select or detech seem edge in shader editor thank you :)
I want the wrinkle to appear around the , seem edge containing the normal map.
[image]

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. I think you are not using any terminology correctly. Seams are usually not 'selected' in the shader editor - that makes no sense as you work with nodes in shader editor, also edges or wrinkles do not contain normal maps - that also makes no sense. I suggest you edit the question and explain in more detail what you mean to ask. If you want to make wrinkles, you can use sculpting in Blender, you could bake higher resolution mesh detail to a normal map in order to be able to have a lower resolution mesh showing more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you mean, this little GN modifier will grab the UV-seam edges and output  'Is UV seam' as an attribute on face-corners:

[image]

It splits all edges, transforms the mesh geometry to its own UV map, re-welds by distance, and  then transfers 'Is boundary edge' back to the original mesh, by face-corner index.

The output `Attribute` is available to shaders. The seam-bump, below, is procedurally generated from the mesh's UV map.

[image]

[image]